# Adding jQuery datepicker for more than one text box in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 application. In one of my partial views I render all fields that should provide the option to select date. I use the jQuery datepicker plugin and some sample code I found on the net :

```
if (field[i].MCS_Fields.FieldTypeId == 2)
                    { 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                        @field[i].QuestionText;
                        @Html.TextBox("datepicker", "", new { @class = "datepicker" })
                    }
```

The problem is that if I do this for more than one `@Html.TextBox` no matter where I pick the date the change will be made only on the first textbox with `class="datepicker"`. I have almost no experience with JS, jQuery and so on, so could you suggest a way that will allow me to add `N` number of `@Html.TextBox` and being able to pick a date for each one separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on your page bottom,it will render all datepickers:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

**Edit**:
If it doesn't work i guess may be you put it in wrong place so the code run before html rendered,try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9GKt/)

Comment: I added this at the end of my page but still all changes go to the first textbox.

Comment: No idea why it's not working for me. I'll accept your answer as it seems it does what I need, and probably I'm doing something wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
Using each function:

```
  $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });
```

If this is not working, then you can use this also:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
     $(function () {
         $("#StartDate").datepicker();
     });
  </script>
```

Here  `StartDate` will be id of your datepicker. and you can write this in your view

Comment: Well, where exactly should I write this. You can see Eli's answer which is exactly like yours but it doesn't work for some reason. Probably I'm writing the code at wrong place, dunno... Should I leave it at the end of the page as jarvanJiang says or I have to write it every time instead my code from the original post?

Comment: you can write this in your view. Probably at the end, place it in `<div></div>`. and just write `<script type=text/javascript>`. tell me if this will work